# how to control struct member behavior with struct const pointer as function parameter?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I have a C code, somewhat similar to this:

```
struct st
{
    int *var;
}

void fun(st *const ptr)
{
    // considering memory for struct is already initialized properly.
    ptr->var = NULL; // NO_ERROR
    ptr = NULL; // ERROR, since its a const pointer.
}

void main()
{ 
    //considering memory for struct is initialized properly
    fun(ptr);
}
```

I dont want to declare `int *var` as `const` in the structure definition, so as not to mess with the huge code base. Not looking to make any change in the structure definition
Is there any way in C, to get an error for the `NO_ERROR` line
`ptr->var = NULL; // NO_ERROR` ?

Comment: Can you please be more precise about _"Is there any way in C, to get an error for the NO_ERROR line"_? Do you ask if `ptr->var = NULL` may cause undefined behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the parameter with const, so the `ptr` is a pointer to a const object:

```
void fun(const struct st* ptr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration makes `ptr` to be constant, but not the object to which it points. Also don't miss `struct` keyword

```
void fun(struct st *const ptr);
```

Instead you should use

```
void fun(const struct st *ptr);
```

Such declaration allows to change pointer but not the object to which it points.

Answer (score 0):

Keep this in mind:

- With `type* const ptr`, you cannot change the pointer but you can change the pointed data
- With `const type* ptr`, you can change the pointer but you cannot change the pointed data

So all you need is to replace `struct st* const ptr` with `const struct st* ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Superb! Thank you so much guys! 
I did this - 
void fun(const struct st *const ptr);
and I was able to get an error while changing both ptr and ptr->var .. Just what I needed..